# How does 1-bromo-2-fluorobenzene react with lithium amalgam?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, organometallic-compounds

How does this organometallic reagent react with 1-bromo-2-fluorobenzene? Does it react like Grignard reagent? If the product of this reaction is then reacted with furan, what will be the final product? I can guess there will be a benzyne intermediate, but I am not sure.

Comment: At what temperature is this reaction taking place?

Comment: Benzyne does a Diels-Alder with furan

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question lacks context: This question needs revision before it is ready for a great answer. Please edit to include how this question came up and how you tried to answer it. This will help writing an answer that is useful for you and for others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from Page 1063 of Advanced Organic Chemistry FIFTH EDITION, Part B - 
Reactions and Synthesis, FRANCIS A. CAREY, and RICHARD J. SUNDBERG:

> Benzyne can also be generated from o-dihaloaromatics. Reaction with lithium amalgam or magnesium results in the formation of transient organometallic compounds that decompose with elimination of lithium halide. o-Fluorobromobenzene is the usual starting material in this procedure.
>
> [image]

As @orthocresol said in the comments that Benzyne undergoes Diels-Alder reaction with furan.

The first Diels–Alder reaction of benzyne with furan was performed before giving a 76% yield of the adduct, which was converted to 1-naphthol with acid${^1}$ ${^2}$.

[image]

**From Diels-Alder adduct to 1-naphthol**

[image]

In the absence of the furan trapping agent, biphenylene and triphenylene were obtained in yields of 24 and 3% respectively${^3}$.

[image]

**References**

${^1}$:https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273556121_The_Benzyne_Story

${^2}$ :Shashidher et al., Pharm Anal Acta 2011, 2:7
DOI: 10.4172/2153-2435.1000137

${^3}$ :https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273556121_The_Benzyne_Story

Comment: It is worth noting that  F is a moderate directing/stabilising group for lithiation so ortho-lithio- fluorobenzene are stable at dry ice/acetone temperatures.